# Qdebug display hex value

Tags: qt, qdebug

I am trying to display a number using QDebug in the Hex format. Below is the code which I have written.  It is working but the output has string contents enclosed in double quotes:

How to remove these quotes?

```
m_CanMsg_ptr->id = 0x720;
m_CanMsg_ptr->sizeData = 1;
m_CanMsg_ptr->data[0] = 0x05;

MessageID.setNum(m_CanMsg_ptr->id,16);
DataSize  = QString("%1").arg(m_CanMsg_ptr->sizeData, 0, 16);
data      = QString("%1").arg(m_CanMsg_ptr->data[0], 0, 16)

qDebug() << "Heart-Beat : Msg ID = " << MessageID << "  Msg DLC = " << DataSize;
qDebug() << "Msg Data " << " = " << data;
```

I did as per these resources:

http://forum.qt.io/topic/5003/moved-how-to-display-a-local-variable-in-hex-when-debugging-a-qt-app/2
http://qt.shoutwiki.com/wiki/Convert_hexadecimal_to_decimal_and_vice-versa_in_Qt

[image]

Comment: Did you try using the ``+`` Operator instead of ``<<`` for concatenating the strings?

Comment: tried this but problem is half solved .... but yet full string is displayed with quotes .. ? How to remove this quotes

Comment: i get following output with quotes after replacing << with + .. "Heart-Beat : Msg ID =  720  Msg DLC = 1"

Comment: You remove quotes by using qDebug().noquote()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`qDebug` is a debug interface. It's not meant for custom-formatted output, it's simply a way of quickly getting data in readable form. It's meant for a developer, and the quotes are there to remind you that you've output a string. `qDebug()` presumes that the `const char*` data is a message and shows it without quotes, other string types like `QString` are "just data" and are shown with quotes.

If you want custom formatting, don't use `qDebug()`, use `QTextStream`:

```
#include <QTextStream>
#include <cstdio>

QTextStream out(stdout);

void f() {
   out << "Heart-Beat : Msg ID = " << MessageID << "  Msg DLC = " << DataSize << endl;
}
```

Comment: Completeness it might be good to add: out << std::hex << MessageID << ...

Comment: `out` is not an `std::ostream`, so `std::hex` won’t compile. But `hex` all by itself will (it’s Qt’s, not `std`’s).

Comment: The correct(?) way in Qt is `Qt::hex(out) << number;` or even `Qt::showBase(Qt::hex(out)) << number;` Or, for better readability IMHO: `Qt::showbase(Qt::uppercasedigits(Qt::hex(out))) << number;`

Comment: Sadly, to get what want, I needed: `out << "0x" << QString("%1").arg(number, 8, 16, QLatin1Char('0')).toUpper();`  Which just looks ugly. But it seems the simplest that gives me the same as `printf("0x%08X", number);`

Comment: @JesseChisholm Unfortunately, "streaming" string formatting was a failed STL experiment. Modern string fromatting eschews that old interface, and comes back to printf-like API in modern C++. But that's not in Qt yet.

Comment: @UnslanderMonica I suppose this would be always a point of debate (also, new interface is nothing like printf). The problem of format string output is its fragility to usage, portability OR high cost, choose two of those. Problem of stl-like implementation was its annoying  "I toggle it once and untoggle after" approach to output modes, but supposedly it had to generate a compile time , static sequence of operations upon stream, no excess memory allocation, stack crawling and parsing a string, no dependency on the actual types of arguments changing from platform to platform.

Answer (score 40):

The solution is simple:

```
#include <QDebug>

int value = 0x12345;
qDebug() << "Value : " << hex << value;
```

Comment: "Furthermore, QTextStream manipulators can be piped into a QDebug stream." -- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdebug.html#formatting-options

Comment: [QTextStream also defines several global manipulator functions](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#qtextstream-manipulators)

Comment: It should be noted that if the value is a char, this will not work, but can be easily resolved by casting the char to an int which then makes it work.

Comment: As of Qt 5.14, `hex` is exposed through the Qt namespace, `Qt::hex`, and you can use it with and without the `Qt::` prefix. As of Qt 5.15, `hex` is deprecated and `Qt::hex` is the preferred usage.

Comment: To show the `0x` prefix, use `Qt::hex << Qt::showbase << your_value`

Answer (score 28):

You could format string first:

```
int myValue = 0x1234;
QString valueInHex= QString("%1").arg(myValue , 0, 16);
qDebug() << "value = " << valueInHex;
```

Answer (score 14):

Another way of doing this would be:

```
int value = 0xFFFF;
qDebug() << QString::number(value, 16);
```

Hope this helps.

Edit:
To remove the quotes you can cast the number as a pointer, as qt will format that without using quotes.  For instance:

```
int value = 0xFFFF;
qDebug() << (void *) value;
```

Slightly hackish, but it works.

Comment: +1 for being more efficient than `qDebug() << QByteArray(...)` (that produces a QString internally), but this too does not answer OP's question on how to get rid of the quotes.

Comment: I must have missed that, I updated my answer with something that will remove quotes.

Comment: Use noquote(), as in: qDebug().noquote() << QString::number(value, 16);

Answer (score 7):

If one is not tied to use streaming operators, can go with the plain old `%x` and use qDebug with formatting string:

```
int hexnum = 0x56;
qDebug("My hex number is: %x", hexnum);
```

which will yield "My hex number is: 56", without quotes.

Comment: FYI, this implies that `hexnum` is unsigned

Answer (score 4):

```
qDebug() << QByteArray::number(myNumber).toHex()
```

Comment: This does not remove the quotes as asked. Also, this produces more internal overhead than necessary: QByteArray::number(myNumber) creates a QByteArray with the decimal representation which then needs a second step for converting to hex.
 
Suggested improvement:

`qDebug() << QByteArray::number(myNumber,16)`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `noquote()` to avoid the quotation marks. As in:

```
qDebug().noquote() << QString::number(value, 16);
```

Answer (score 2):

May be a little late, but in case someone needs this:

As statet in the answere by Kuber Ober, Qt only removes the quotes if it's a `const char *` passed to `qDebug`. However, Qt provides a macro to do the same with a `QString` - The `qPrintable` macro:

```
qDebug() << qPrintable(QString("String without quotes")) << QString("String with quotes");
```

This way, you can use the `QString::number` function (as provided by TheDancinZerg) to format the string:

```
int value = 0xFFFF;
qDebug() << qPrintable(QString::number(value, 16));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int value = 0xff005542;
qDebug() << QString("%1").arg(value , 0, 16).toUpper();
```

> >>> FF005542

That'll give you hex output at whatever length is required. But if you'd like fixed width output, this is handy (example of four hex digits):

```
int value = 0xff;
qDebug() << QString("%1").arg(value, 4, 16, (QChar)'0').toUpper();
//      Here's the fixed field length⬆︎
```

> >>> 00FF

Answer (score 1):

Just a note! The method using `<<hex` is deprecieted now, so it's recommended to use:

```cpp
#include <QDebug>

int num = 0x4321;
qDebug() << "Hex num: " <<Qt::hex << num;
```

Because, if you compile this way just using `<<hex` you will got some warnings, what means that soon this form to write will not be compatible anymore. For more infos take a look at  [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This is why you want to learn C before C++ & Qt:

```cpp
qDebug("Data for test case 1: 0x%04X", crc)
```

Done, always works.  No extra spaces, no extra quotes, no extra `.noquote` or `<<` or `::hex` or `.toUpper` etc.