# WlanQueryInterface data enumeration

Tags: c++, windows, wlanapi

I want to get `wlan_intf_opcode_bss_type` using `WlanQueryInterface` function.

**My code:**

```
PDOT11_BSS_TYPE wlanInterfaceState = NULL;
DWORD wlanInterfaceStateSize = sizeof(wlanInterfaceState);
DWORD interfaceStateResult;
interfaceStateResult = WlanQueryInterface(hClient, &pIfInfo->InterfaceGuid, wlan_intf_opcode_bss_type, NULL, &wlanInterfaceStateSize, (PVOID *)&wlanInterfaceState, NULL);

if (interfaceStateResult != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
  qDebug() << "Error";
} else {
  qDebug() << wlanInterfaceState;
}
```

I get hexadecimal values. When I use switch to enumerate on `wlanInterfaceState` I get error:

```
error: C2450: switch expression of type 'PDOT11_BSS_TYPE' is illegal
```

**Update:**
`DOT11_BSS_TYPE` enumeration syntax from MSDN:

```
typedef enum _DOT11_BSS_TYPE { 
  dot11_BSS_type_infrastructure  = 1,
  dot11_BSS_type_independent     = 2,
  dot11_BSS_type_any             = 3
} DOT11_BSS_TYPE, *PDOT11_BSS_TYPE;
```

How to use these enumerations on `wlanInterfaceState`?
Thanks.

Comment: Even if you are using qt, that's not a Qt question. you should remove this tag.

Comment: My suggestion. Try using QTextStream instead QDebug. Have a look -> [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358967/qdebug-display-hex-value)

Comment: I use qDebug() just for testing purpose. I want to display actual data in QLabel (setText function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I use the pointer `wlanInterfaceState` version, so using it with switch is not considered correct expression.

**Switch (condition) statement**

condition - any expression of integral or enumeration type, or of a class type contextually implicitly convertible to an integral or enumeration type, or a declaration of a single non-array variable of such type with a brace-or-equals initializer.

Since it points to enum, then I need to dereference it.

So the switch statement should look like this:

```
 switch (*wlanInterfaceState) {
         case dot11_BSS_type_infrastructure:
              qDebug() << "Infastructure";
         break;

         case dot11_BSS_type_independent:
              qDebug() << "Independent";
         break;

         case dot11_BSS_type_any:
              qDebug() << "Any";
         break;

         default:
              qDebug() << "Unknown";
         }
```